# Jquery UI and HTML5 datepicker - date not formatting correctly

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make a date picker which will operate for browsers that have implemented the html5 specification and provide a jquery ui date picker for those that don't.

So far I have:

```
<input type="date" id="TargetDate1" name="TargetDate1" class="date" value="2013-06-29" min="2013-06-26" max="2016-06-26" required="required" autocomplete="off">
```

which works fine in Chrome27 providing the native html5 control and formats the date correctly in British format dd/mm/yyyy both before selection and after. I am using the following jquery to provide a jquery ui date picker:

```
 if (Modernizr.inputtypes.date === false) {
     $('.date').datepicker({
         changeMonth: true,
         changeYear: true,
         minDate: 0,
         maxDate: "+3Y"
     }).prop("min", "").prop("max", "");
 }
```

I have also used the following internationalisation file to format the date and also tried specifying dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' in the above as well.

```
/*global jQuery */

/* English/UK initialisation for the jQuery UI date picker plugin. */
/* Written by Stuart. */
jQuery(function ($) {
     $.datepicker.regional['en-GB'] = {
          closeText: 'Done',
          prevText: 'Prev',
          nextText: 'Next',
          currentText: 'Today',
          monthNames: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
          monthNamesShort: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
          dayNames: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday',         
    'Friday',     'Saturday'],
          dayNamesShort: ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'],
          dayNamesMin: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
          weekHeader: 'Wk',
          dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
          firstDay: 1,
          isRTL: false,
          showMonthAfterYear: false,
          yearSuffix: ''
     };
     $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['en-GB']);
});
```

In a non-html5 browser, when a user picks a date (such as in FF22) using the Jquery UI datepicker it provides the date in the correct format: dd/mm/yyyy to the form. The problem is that when the form loads initially, the format of the date is in yyyy-mm-dd format which is incorrect.

Is there anyway of making jquery or some other method format the date correctly for all scenarios?

Also I have noticed that by specifying min="2013-06-26" max="2016-06-26" to FF it won't let me save the data unless it is again in yyyy-mm-dd format. Hence in the jquery above it blanks it out. If anyone has a way of using the html5 tags in the jquery or not having to blank out the min/max, that would be useful. Thanks

Comment: is your datepicker working in FF22? for me it is not working?  can you check?

Comment: Hi, yes it is working fine. I'm using jquery latest.

Comment: if possible make a JSFiddle, I'm not able to get it.

Comment: I got it. few clarifications, in firefox it is showing as `2013-06-29` and in chrome `29-06-2013`, what is your expectation?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/cvmz8/5/

Comment: my expectation is that it will display as 29/06/2013. In chrome I get this

Comment: check the jsfiddle (using FF22) in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comments you need to have dd/mm/yyyy date format for unsupported browser.

If this is correct, then try below one.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (Modernizr.inputtypes.date === false) {
        var date = new Date($('#TargetDate1').val());
        $('#TargetDate1').val(("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + date.getFullYear());
        $('.date').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            minDate: 0,
            maxDate: "+3Y"
        }).prop("min", "").prop("max", "");
    }
});
```

To change the date format you need this:

```
var date = new Date($('#TargetDate1').val());
$('#TargetDate1').val(("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + date.getFullYear());
```

Demo in [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/cvmz8/8/)

Comment: that's great, I clearly misunderstood the purpose of dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' in Jquery datepicker. I thought this was meant to do the formatting for you.

Comment: if (Modernizr.inputtypes.date === false) {
        $('.date').each(function () {
            $(this).datepicker({
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                minDate: 0,
                maxDate: "+3Y"
            }).prop("min", "").prop("max", "");
            var targetDate = $(this).val();
            if (targetDate !== "") {
                var date = new Date(targetDate);
                $(this).val(("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "/" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "/" + date.getFullYear())
            }
        });
    }

Comment: @johnstaveley I'm glad that I was able to help.

Comment: @johnstaveley +1 for showing interest, by updating your final code.